# scipy stats geometric mean returns NaN

Tags: python, statistics, numpy, scipy, mean

I am using scipy's gmean() function to determine the geometric mean of a numpy array that contains voltage outputs. The range of the numbers is between -80.0 and 30.0. Currently, the numpy array is two dimensional, giving the voltage for two different measurements.

```
array([[-60.0924, -60.0882],
       [-80.    , -80.    ],
       [-80.    , -80.    ],
       ...,
       [-60.9221, -66.0748],
       [-61.0971, -65.9637],
       [-61.2706, -65.8803]])
```

However, I get NaN when I take the geometric mean:

```
>>> from scipy import stats as scistats
>>> scistats.gmean(voltages)
array([ NaN,  NaN])
```

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to calculate the geometric mean of negative values? It  makes no sense. Do you want to calculate the geometric mean of their absolute values instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The geometric mean cannot be applied to negative values.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have an even number `n` of elements, and an odd number of negative values, you would end up calculating the `n`-th root of a negative number which does not a real-valued solution.